# Geodetic Precession of a Gyroscope in Hartle's GR Book

Tags: general-relativity, gyroscopes, precession

In 14.3, Hartle deduces the geodetic precession angle per orbit of a gyroscope in Schwarzschild geometry. Immediately after eq.(14.18), the book reasons that the angle deduced is physically measured by an observer comoving with the gyro. However, I have questions in this derivation.

1. Eq.(14.17) doesn't make sense to me, since technically $e_\hat{r}$ and $\frac{s(t)}{s_*}$ are not in the same tangent space. I guess instead of $e_\hat{r}$, the book intends to consider a vector at the same point as $\frac{s(t)}{s_*}$, with the same components as $e_\hat{r}$ in coordinate basis? If that is the case, we can use the inner product between the two to compute the precession angle, which is a spatial angle, simply because $e_\hat{r}^0=0$?
2. I don't understand the argument that this angle is measured by a comoving observer. In particular, what does "a radial direction in the observer's frame" mean? To me, there seems to be only one meaningful radial direction, namely $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$? But then this will trivally be (0,1,0,0) in Schwarzschild coordinate basis. Besides, in my understanding, Lorentz boost only relates locally inertial frames, but Schwarzchild basis frame is not locally inertial, so how can we use Lorentz boost to transform a vector in an observer's frame to the coordinate frame?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Since SE is a Q&A site, you should follow a few guide lines: 1) only one question per post, 2) write self-contained questions. As it is, your questions are impossible to understand because you only refer to a book many people don't have. It also means that answers wouldn't be beneficial for many people. So you should give additional details and context. Thank you.

Comment: hi 111 and welcome to PSE (physics stack exchange)! I suggest you write something about yourself in your profile, so people can better tune their answers to your stated level of knowledge. Although, strictly speaking @Miyase is correct, this is your first post and your questions are related, so I see no problem with them. When I have a moment, I will check Hartle's Book and hopefully come back with an answer.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. I realize that this may be too specific a question for Physics S.E. I may already know the answer to my own question, and I will write a short answer for future reference later. It will be great if you can confirm my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

After some thoughts, I may have come up with an answer, which is now posted here for confirmation and future reference.

1. Given a tetrad $\{\hat{e}_\alpha\}$, the spatial angle between 4-vectors $u,v$ may be computed from the dot product (as opposed to the full scalar product) $u^i v_i$, where $\alpha=0,1,2,3$ and $i=1,2,3$. In particular, we can construct a tetrad from the Schwarzschild coordinate basis, which corresponds to a stationary observer. The spatial angle between $e_{\hat{r}}$ and $\frac{s(t)}{s_*}$ can therefore be computed in this tetrad from the full scalar product as in Eq.(14.17) since $e_{\hat{r}}^0=0$. Thus, Eq.(14.18) gives the precession angle measured by a stationary observer.
2. Now we can meaningfully talk about Lorentz boost between this stationary observer  and the comoving observer. The full scalar product of $e_{\hat{r}}$ and $\frac{s(t)}{s_*}$ remains the same in the comoving observer's tetrad. The spatial angle measured by this comoving observer can be computed from the dot product in his tetrad, which is again equal to the full scalar product, since in the comoving observer's tetrad $e_{\hat{r}}^0=0$.